# Control threads using AutoResetEvent in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, oop, autoresetevent

Say I have a class A and a class B representing tasks.
I want to perform an experiment, and for the experiment to start I need to finish at least 5 B tasks and only 1 A task.

I have the following classes

```
abstract class Task   
{ 
    public int Id;

    public void Start(object resetEvent)
    {
        EventWaitHandle ewh = (EventWaitHandle)resetEvent;

        Thread.Sleep(new Random(DateTime.Now.Ticks.GetHashCode()).Next(5000, 14000));
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} starts",this.GetType().Name, Id);
        ewh.Set();
    }
}

class A : Task
{
    static int ID = 1;
    public A(EventWaitHandle resetEvent)
    {
        Id = ID++;
        new Thread(StartTask).Start(resetEvent);
    }
}

class B : Task
{
    static int ID = 1;
    public B(EventWaitHandle resetEvent)
    {
        Id = ID++;
        new Thread(StartTask).Start(resetEvent);
    }
}
```

and the following main

```
static void Main()
{
    A a;

    B[] bs = new B[20];
    int numberOfBs = 0;

    EventWaitHandle aResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    EventWaitHandle bResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    a = new A(aResetEvent);
    for (int i = 0; i < bs.Length; i++)
        bs[i] = new B(bResetEvent);

    while (numberOfBs < 5)
    {
        bResetEvent.WaitOne();
        numberOfBs++;
    }
    aResetEvent.WaitOne();

    Console.WriteLine("Experiment started with {0} B's!", numberOfBs);
    Thread.Sleep(3000); // check how many B's got in the middle
    Console.WriteLine("Experiment ended with {0} B's!", numberOfBs);
}
```

now I have few problems/questions:

1. How can I wait for only N signals out of possible M?
2. Can I achieve the result I'm looking for with only 1 AutoResetEvent?
3. I don't understand why all the tasks are printed together, I expected each task to be printed when it is done and now when everything is done.
4. is the following code thread safe?

.

```
while (numberOfBs < 5)
{
    bResetEvent.WaitOne();
    numberOfBs++;
}
```

could it be that couple of threads signal together? if so, can I fix that using lock on bResetEvent?

Comment: Maybe you should be using `CountdownEvent` instead of `AutoResetEvent`?

Comment: "Can I achieve the result I'm looking", what are the results that you are looking for?

Comment: @YacoubMassad  I am obligated to use this a ResetEvent even though I will look into this CountDownEvent.
As for the wanted results - I want to be able to control when 5 B tasks and 1 A task are finished

Comment: _"I want to be able to control when 5 B tasks and 1 A task are finished"_ -- "control" in what way? You can "control" them without any synchronization at all; i.e. by starting them, you've controlled them such that they will finish "soon" (that's the "when"). Presumably that's not the kind of "control" you mean. What _do_ you mean? Please be _specific_.

Comment: I meant to be in control of exactly when they are finished, for example I want to be able to tell when atleast 5 B and 1 A are finished

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1.How can I wait for only N signals out of possible M?

Just as you do here (sort of…see answer to #4).

> 2.Can I achieve the result I'm looking for with only 1 AutoResetEvent?

Yes. But you will need two counters in that case (one for the `A` type and one for the `B` type), and they will need to be accessed in a thread-safe way, e.g. with the `Interlocked` class, or using a `lock` statement. All threads, `A` and `B` types, will share the same `AutoResetEvent`, but increment their own type's counter. The main thread can monitor each counter and process once both counters are at their desired value (`1` for the `A` counter, `5` for the `B` counter).

I'd recommend using the `lock` statement approach, as it's simpler and would allow you to avoid using `AutoResetEvent` altogether (the `lock` statement uses the `Monitor` class, which provides some functionality similar to `AutoResetEvent`, while also providing the synchronization needed to ensure coherent use of the counters.

Except that you've written in the comments you have to use `AutoResetEvent` (why?), so I guess you're stuck with `Interlocked` (no point in using `lock` if you're not going to take full advantage).

> 3.I don't understand why all the tasks are printed together, I expected each task to be printed when it is done and now when everything is done.

Because you have a bug. You should be creating a single `Random` instance and using it to determine the duration of every task. You can either compute the durations in the thread that creates each task, or you can synchronize access (e.g. with `lock`) and use the same `Random` object in multiple threads.

What you *can't* do is create a whole new `Random` object using the same seed value for every thread, because then each thread (or at least large blocks of them, depending on timing) is going to wind up getting the exact same "random" number to use as its duration.

You see all the output coming out together, because *that's when it happens*: all together.

(And yes, if you create multiple `Random` objects in quick succession, they will all get the same seed, whether you use `DateTime.Now` yourself explicitly, or just let the `Random` class do it. The tick counter used for the seed is not updated frequently enough for concurrently running threads to see different values.)

> 4.is the following code thread safe?

The code in question:

```
while (numberOfBs < 5)
{
    bResetEvent.WaitOne();
    numberOfBs++;
}
```

…is thread safe, because the only data shared between the thread executing that loop and any other thread is the `AutoResetEvent` object, and that object is itself thread-safe.

That is, for the usual understanding of "thread safe". I highly recommend you read Eric Lippert's article [What is this thing you call "thread safe"?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/10/19/what-is-this-thing-you-call-thread-safe/) Asking if something is thread-safe is a much more complicated question that you probably realize.

In particular, while the code is thread-safe in the usual way (i.e. data remains coherent), as you note it is possible for more than one thread to reach the `Set()` call before the main thread can react to the first. Thus you may miss some notifications.

Comment: I have to use AutoResetEvent as this is a class exercise and this is what I have been asked to do.

Comment: how can I get all the notifications? without missing any?

Comment: _"how can I get all the notifications?"_ -- If you use `Interlocked` and have each thread increment the relative counter, then while the main thread may wake fewer times than the event is set, you will be guaranteed that when it does wake, the counter it's examining will indicate the actual number of completed threads. Another alternative is to use two `AutoResetEvent` objects, where the main thread waits on one, while the task threads wait on the other, such that only one task thread at a time is allowed to set the event that wakes the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

The task that requires taks A and B reach certain changes could be notified each time a task is done. When it gets notified it could check if the conditions are good and proceed only then.

Output:

```
Task 3 still waiting: A0, B0
B reached 1
Task 3 still waiting: A0, B1
A reached 1
Task 3 still waiting: A1, B1
B reached 2
Task 3 still waiting: A1, B2
B reached 3
Task 3 still waiting: A1, B3
A reached 2
Task 3 still waiting: A2, B3
B reached 4
Task 3 still waiting: A2, B4
B reached 5
Task 3 done: A2, B5
A reached 3
B reached 6
B reached 7
B reached 8
B reached 9
B reached 10
All done
```

Program:

```
class Program
{
    static int stageOfA = 0;
    static int stageOfB = 0;   
    private static readonly AutoResetEvent _signalStageCompleted = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    static void DoA()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            Interlocked.Increment(ref stageOfA);
            Console.WriteLine($"A reached {stageOfA}");
            _signalStageCompleted.Set();
        }
    }

    static void DoB()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(50);
            Interlocked.Increment(ref stageOfB);
            Console.WriteLine($"B reached {stageOfB}");
            _signalStageCompleted.Set();
        }
    }

    static void DoAfterB5andA1()
    {
        while( (stageOfA < 1) || (stageOfB < 5))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Task 3 still waiting: A{stageOfA}, B{stageOfB}");
            _signalStageCompleted.WaitOne();
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"Task 3 done: A{stageOfA}, B{stageOfB}");
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task[] taskArray = { Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoA()),
                                 Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoB()),
                                 Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoAfterB5andA1()) };

        Task.WaitAll(taskArray);
        Console.WriteLine("All done");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```